# SQL Server - Stored Procedure Return in Case Result Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case, procedure

I'd like to use a return from a procedure in a CASE statement. It can't be a function because that procedure returns an inserted key.

```
    UPDATE TIM 
    SET CD_LINHA_EVENTO = 
        CASE WHEN 
            TIM.CD_SUBESTRUTURA_PARAMETRO = (SELECT TOP 1 SPZ.CD_SUBESTRUTURA_PARAMETRO FROM SUBESTRUTURA_PARAMETRO SPZ WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE SPZ.CD_SUBESTRUTURA = TIM.CD_SUBESTRUTURA 
                                                AND SPZ.FL_SELECAO = 1 ORDER BY SPZ.NR_ORDEM)
            THEN 
                **EXEC [dbo].[SPRTO_NumeracaoEventos]**
            ELSE 
            (SELECT MAX(TIM2.CD_LINHA_EVENTO) FROM #TB_INSERTED_MODIFIED TIM2 WITH(NOLOCK))
            END
    FROM #TB_INSERTED_MODIFIED TIM WITH (NOLOCK)
```

stored procedure [SPRTO_NumeracaoEventos]:

```
INSERT INTO TB_NUMERACAO_EVENTOS (VALOR) VALUES ('')
RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to find some other way to implement this logic.  An `update` statement is not the right way.  Perhaps you need a trigger.

Comment: Thank you, @GordonLinoff. Actually, it is already inside a trigger. I was trying to avoid a WHILE loop and update each #TB_INSERTED_MODIFIED row at a time, but I think that should be the way... =\

Comment: Use an OUTPUT parameter, not a RETURN value. RETURN is for error and status codes, not data. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-or-return-instead-of-output.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out your table schema well enough to provide a direct answer, but I put together a way to use inserted identity values within an update trigger. Hopefully you can  adapt this to fit your specific use case.

Have a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78150/1)

As noted in the comments in the fiddle, this strategy is based on using the OUTPUT clause to capture identity values into a table variable. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx for more on the OUTPUT clause.

For rows where the case is true, we insert one row per true case into the secondary table and capture the identities to a table variable, then we update the underlying table with a row number join between the inserted virtual table and the identity table variable. Then we run another update for the rows where the case is false. Here's the relevant trigger code from my fiddle example.

```
-- Create a table variable to hold identity ID values from OUTPUT clause
DECLARE @table_2_ids TABLE (id INT NOT NULL)

-- Insert to our secondary table where the condition is true and capture the identity values to table variable
INSERT table_2 (textval) 
OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @table_2_ids 
SELECT 'from trigger'
FROM inserted
WHERE flag = 1

-- Use row number to match up rows from inserted where the condition is true to the identity value table variable
-- Update matched identity id to underlying table
UPDATE t
SET table_2_id = r.id, textval = textval + ' and trigger inserted to table_2'
FROM table_1 t
JOIN (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn FROM inserted WHERE flag = 1) i ON i.id = t.id
JOIN (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn FROM @table_2_ids) r ON r.rn = i.rn

-- and now update where condition is false
UPDATE t
SET textval = textval + ' and trigger did not insert to table_2'
FROM table_1 t
WHERE flag = 0
```